# How can client get notified of completion status of the request sent to server?-Winsock

Tags: c++11, winsock2

I am in the middle of learning Winsock and came across a conceptual problem in getting notification of request completion status from server. As client is designed only to send while server to receive, is there any way that a client can be notified? Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand if you are asking whether or not the server can send data as a reply on a connected socket, or whether you want the server to somehow initiate a connection with a client after the initial connection is closed?

Comment: `client is designed only to send while server to receive` That's quite an unusual protocol are thinking of here. In a typical protocol - say, HTTP - the client initiates the connection, then sends a request, which the server receives. The server then processes the request and sends the response, which the client receives.

Comment: Hi @LukePark, sorry for the vague question, ya, i am asking whether the server can send data as a reply on a connected socket(client)? Thanks

Comment: A TCP socket is full-duplex: either peer can send and receive, possibly simultaneously. "Client" and "server" are notions of the communication protocol, not the underlying network topology.

Comment: Hi, @IgorTandetnik, thanks for your clarification, sorry for the newbie question but how it can be achieved??

Comment: How can what be achieved? You send with `send()` and you receive with `recv()`. I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, sorry, it is the problem with my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side socket that is used when you call `recv` can also be used to send data.  Remember that the `SOCKET` struct that you get when you accept a client on the server is the same as the `SOCKET` struct on the client side that is used to connect.  Thus after receiving data from the client, you can send a reply like

```
send(s, res_str, strlen(res_str), 0);
```

Where `res_str` is your response string.  Technically `res_str` is `strlen(res_str) + 1` bytes in size but we don't want the null character.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer.  You're welcome.